# MongooseJS save additional params

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using POST query to save data in my app. How can I add additional params to `Item`? I want to add something like `user: req.user._id`.

```
var Item = new Model(req.body);
    Item.save(function (err, model) {
        res.send(model);
    });
```

So my document will look like:

```
{
   param1: '1',
   param2: '2',
   user: ObjectID('blahblahblah')
}
```

From my form I got two params - `param1` and `param2`. `user` parameter was added before saving the document.

Comment: I think it's not clear what you need to do, and what exactly is the issue either you can't get user.id from the req, or you get that parameter but you can't store it in Mongodb please provide more details

Comment: @Siavosh, I couldn't store parameters in MongoDB

Comment: seems your problem is solved, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you mean is adding something **additional** that is not in the form, then it is just a JavaScript object so there is nothing wrong with this:

```
req.body.userId = "Me";
```

And now `req.body` contains your new property that you can pass into your other constructor or even directly save. Try it in a REPL or with `console.log`